# how to import tables into hive with columns having new line characters with sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, impala, sqoop2

I am trying to hive-import a mysql table using sqoop which has a column that stores json data containing new line chars. For handling hive default delimiters, I tried to change the line delimiter using sqoop's --lines-terminated-by '\u002' option. Sqoop gave error saying --lines-terminated-by takes only '\n'. 
--hive-drop-import-delim option allows to import data by dropping new line characters. Is there a way to import data intact into hive as text file?

Comment: Can you try to import data using Cntrl+A as delimiter                                   [ --fields-terminated-by '\001'  ] and skipping the --lines-terminated-by and load into Hive table

Comment: Abhi, Yes. I tried with --fields-terminated-by option. Problem is rows gets terminated with new line character. Since the column data is having new lines, I am getting more records in hive as compared to mysql. I want to import data intact without loosing new line chars in the column data..

Comment: Why not to use parquet or avro instead of text file?

Comment: Currently we have setup sqoop-1.4.5 version and also we have some requirement to store it as text file.

Comment: Did anyone get a solution for this?